# Shorten DataFrame or Shorten CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am reading data from csv file, making calculations, and returning data to a different csv file. I have a DataFrame 100 rows long by 8 columns from the original file. After in place data calculations, the 100 rows of data is "compacted" such that now I only want to return 90 rows of data to the downstream csv file. The system receiving the csv file doesn't like receiving a data file where the last 10 rows are overwritten with all zeros so I'd like to find a way to only write the first 90 rows in the dataframe. Is there a way to do that? From what I have seen "to_csv" doesn't have a built in field for sending less than the entire dataframe to a csv file.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, I would just use [head](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df.head(90).to_csv('yourfile.csv')
```

in this way you can just write the first `n` rows from the beginning of the dataframe to file.